# Optimize Addition(superposition) of 2D Gaussians on GPU

Tags: performance, algorithm, opengl, opengl-es, gpu

I am wondering if there are faster ways(either algorithms or faster gaussian calculations) to achieve the following on the GPU(so the code is inside the fragment shader)

There are two inputs:

1. A 2D grid(e.g Image).
2. an array(10~20) of 2D gaussians (each described by `center_x,center_y,std_x,std_y,angle`)

What I want to do is for each point `(x,y)` in the gird, calculate the superposition(addition) of all the gaussians.

What I am doing right now is to loop through all points in the grid, and for each point I evalute for all gaussians and sum it up.

The Gaussian function I am using is the following:

```
highp float gaussian2DUnnormalized(highp float x,highp float y,highp float mx, highp float my,highp float stdx,highp float stdy, highp float radian) {

     if (abs(stdx) < 0.00001 || abs(stdy) < 0.00001)
         return 0.0;

     highp float stdx2 = stdx * stdx;
     highp float stdy2 = stdy * stdy;

     highp float a = cos(radian) * cos(radian) / (2.0 * stdx2) + sin(radian) * sin(radian) / (2.0 * stdy2);
     highp float b = sin(2.0 * radian) *( -1.0/(4.0 * stdx2) + 1.0/(4.0 * stdy2));

     highp float c = sin(radian) * sin(radian) / (2.0 * stdx2) + cos(radian) * cos(radian) / (2.0 * stdy2);

     highp float result = exp(-1.0* (a * (x - mx)*(x - mx) + 2.0 * b * (x - mx)*(y - my) + c * (y - my)*(y - my)));
     return min(max(result,0.0),1.0);
 }
```

Comment: You could start by precomputing the covariance matrix for each Gaussian so that there's no trig (but still one exponential) in the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you David! Implemented two methods based on your comments and achieved more than 70% speed improvement! Here are the two things I did: 1. pre-calculate covariance matrix to avoid sin and cos calculation 2. directly return 0.0 if the current point is 3.0 sigma away from center. It seems the performance is good enough now. If I need more improvement I'll expand the exp function. Thanks!